# Bootstrap ui carousel empty

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

```
<carousel interval="myInterval">
    <slide ng-repeat="slide in behaviorDataset track by $index" ng-swipe-right="showPrev()" ng-swipe-left="showNext()">
        <img ng-src="slide.image">
    </slide>
</carousel>

var changeImagelist = function (imageList) {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        $scope.behaviorDataset = imageList;
    });
}
```

Here above you find some code for my carousel. But something strange happens. I click on a button and then a modal box will appear with this carousel. But every time i click on the button normally it should be other images.

The first time it works correctly the second time i open the modal box with the carousel in it and you see no data. But when you inspect the code with google chrome you see the source code of the images that should be visible in the carousel.

How can i fix this problem?

----- update -----

I made some example in plunker here you can see the issue that i have.
First you need to click on click me. Then you will see the carousel with some items. Close the modal box then. and switch the images and click again on click me. Then you will see the carousel is empty.

http://plnkr.co/edit/YASfl9nF0cxqlytFjjI0?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

in your controller define a function to get the pictures and use that in the HTML

controller:

```
$scope.getSlides = function(){
    return $scope.behaviorDataset;
}
```

in your ng-repeat:

```
<slide ng-repeat="slide in getSlides() track by $index" ng-swipe-right="showPrev()" ng-swipe-left="showNext()">
    <img ng-src="slide.image">
</slide>
```

Comment: This does not work for me. It is the same first time i open the modal box, I see my images. Second time they are gone but the ng-repeat did his work i think a bug in the carousel directive